# mod_rewrite RewriteRule to handle HTML Entities

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

For some reason, we recieving a bunch of inbound traffic on URLs that contain HTML entities.

E.g.

`http://www.ourdomain.com/index.php?key1=value1&amp;key2=value2`

I want to create a RewriteRule to replace these HTML entities (specifically &amp; with &), and forward people on to the corrected address.

I'm tried these:

`RewriteRule &amp; & [R=permanent]`

and

`RewriteRule &amp; &`

But nothing is happening.

(BTW. I know this is a horrible and dangerous way to solve someone else's problem, but I just need to get it done. temporarily)

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick;

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)&amp;(.*)
RewriteRule .* /index.php?%1&%2 [N,R=301]
```

This essentially says;

- Is there an `&amp;` in the query string?
- If yes, match everything before and after it, then sandwich them together with an `&`
- The `N` flag in the rule effectively says 'keep doing this until the condition no longer makes a match'

Check out the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html), including [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) and [rule flags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewrite_flags.html#flags).

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly.  Did EXACTLY what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

For any rewrite to work, the rewrite engine must be on, but perhaps you already have that fixed:

```
# following statement must come before any other rewrite statements
# and must be enabled per virtual host configuration
RewriteEngine On
```

The ampersand is a special metacharacter. Apparently the people that have copied and pasted your links did so inside an editor which duely escaped the ampersands into `&amp;` (or, more technically correct, `&amp;amp;` if it happened inside an a-tag). I'm not 100% sure, but I find it likely that the ampersand should be escaped, try this:

```
RewriteRule \&amp; \&
```

To find out how the rewrite goes, what it rewrites and why, you should turn rewrite logging on (make sure Apache can write to the location of `RewriteLog`):

```
RewriteLog "somepath.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

where level 9 is the highest.

Comment: I thin I've discovered why it doesn't work: the RewriteRule isn't applied to the query string part of the URL... I'm trying to find if it's possible to re-write the query string portion, but it's not looking likely...