# How can I replace '&amp;' with '&' in my url via htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to replace `&amp;` with `&` in my url via the `.htaccess` file using the following code:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)&amp;(.*)$ /$1&$2 [L,R=301]
```

The context is that I am using woocommerce, the user accesses an order review page (`/checkout/order-pay/1111/?pay_for_order=true&key=wc_order_569cda450dc6a`), which sends them to our company payment portal, however the returned url is coming back as:

```
/checkout/order-pay/3437/?pay_for_order=true&amp;key=wc_order_569cda450dc6a.
```

This change in url breaks the woocommerce functionality (ie the order in question does not load).

How can I change all instances on `&amp;` in urls on my site to `&` using the `.htaccess` file?

Thanks.

Comment: It would be preferable to correct the code generating `&amp;` instead of trying to getting ride of it via .htaccess.

Comment: I agree completely, however I don't have access to that piece of software, I can only work with what my site is receiving unfortunately.

I tried using this method (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229371/mod-rewrite-rewriterule-to-handle-html-entities) but I couldn't make it work sadly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&amp;(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1&%2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Perfect. I was so close as well, but I always fall down with that syntax. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you please accept this answer if it solved your problem ? [How does accepting an answer work ?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had clicked the tick. Thanks very much.